# Print code refuses to work

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this code in Python, and I want to print a text in the color entered by the user can be found in a variable. This is how the code looks like

```
Counter = 1
While True:
           rainbow="Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Voilet"
color = input ("Enter your rainbow color;")
```

**This print color code doesn't work even if the condition evaluate to true.**

```
if color.lower () in rainbow:
    print (color)

if Counter == 4
    break
Counter = Counter +1
```

Comment: In what universe will a color forced lowercase (like `red`) ever match the color `Red` in that string? :-)

Comment: Also the capitalized `Print` should raise a `NameError`. Do you **run** your code before posting ?

Comment: Ok, thanks but from what I was taught the ".lower()" object can for an uppercase string to a lowercase.

Comment: lower() returns the value in `color` as lowercase but the values in `rainbow` are in ProperCase

Answer (score 1):

Not the easiest way to solve the problem. I supposed your code should look something like this

```
Counter = 1
while True:
    rainbow="red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,voilet"
    color = input ("Enter your rainbow color")
    if color.lower() in rainbow:
        print(color)
    if Counter == 4:
        break
    Counter = Counter +1
```

But why didn't you use regular `while`?

```
Counter = 1
while Counter < 4:
    rainbow="red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,voilet"
    color = input ("Enter your rainbow color ")
    if color.lower() in rainbow:
        print(color)
    Counter += 1
```

ALso if you want to leave your first letter capitalized just change if statement like this (read bout String slicing if you haven't yet)

```
if color[0] + color[1:len(color)].lower() in rainbow:
        print(color)
```

The easiest way:

```
Counter = 1
while Counter < 4:
    rainbow="Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Voilet"
    color = input ("Enter your rainbow color ")
    l = rainbow.split(",")
    if color.title() in l:
        print(color)
    Counter += 1
```

Comment: Could also use color.title() instead of color.lower()

Comment: Kirill, thanks for your help, but the code still doesn't work fine if I enter a word say "yello", instead of "yellow" I still get the word "yello" printed even though the if statement evaluate that to false.

Comment: You can use `color[1:]` instead of `color[1:len(color)]`, Python assumes that it is to the end of the string. You can also use `.capitalize()`, it will automatically lowercase everything and uppercase the first letter. Note that `capitalize()` is different from `title()`; the former only capitalizes the first letter, the latter capitalizes every first letter delimited by a space.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code. The main ones are these:

1. `while` not `While`
2. Bad indentation
3. `rainbow` is a string, not a list
4. `rainbow` contains capitalized strings

Firstly, Python is a case sensitive programming language, if you were to use `While` instead of `while` in your code, it will throw you an error. However, I trust that it is just a copy-and-paste error as that is not the problem that you raised.

Secondly, your code is not properly indented. Although the two sections are disjoint in your question, I assume it is:

```
Counter = 1
while True:
    rainbow="Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Voilet"
color = input ("Enter your rainbow color;")

if color.lower () in rainbow:
    print (color)

if Counter == 4
    break
Counter = Counter +1
```

Which would mean that your code will just stay in the `while True:` loop forever. What I think you intended to do was to get 4 valid user inputs and then leave the loop. In that case, you should indent your code under the `while` loop:

```
Counter = 1
while True:
    rainbow="Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Voilet"
    color = input ("Enter your rainbow color;")

    if color.lower () in rainbow:
        print (color)

    if Counter == 4
        break
    Counter = Counter +1
```

Another way is to use the condition to `break` instead of `True`:

```
Counter = 1
while Counter != 4:
    rainbow="Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Voilet"
    color = input ("Enter your rainbow color;")

    if color.lower () in rainbow:
        print (color)

    Counter = Counter +1
```

Thirdly, as you would want to only match the colours that you have defined, using a string won't cut it. When you use a string, the following expression evaluates `True`:

```
"lue" in "Blue" # == True
```

As Python just checks if the value `"lue"` is in the string `"Blue"`. Similarly, if you use a long string such as `"Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Voilet"`, it will do the same thing.

What you want is a list. The following evaluates `False`:

```
"lue" in ["Blue"] # == False
```

Now Python looks at it in a different manner. Is `"lue"` in the **list** `["Blue"]`? The answer is no. So, you should use:

```
["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", "Voilet"]
```

Or, if you want to do it dynamically, `.split(",")` will generate it for you:

```
"Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Voilet".split(",")
```

After that, you will get code like:

```
Counter = 1
while True:

    rainbow=["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", "Voilet"]
    color = input("Enter your rainbow color;")

    if color.lower() in rainbow:
        print(color)

    if Counter == 4
        break
    Counter = Counter +1
```

However, it will still not work because you are matching words such as `"Red"` to `"red"` all the time. You are using `.lower()` to lowercase the whole input. Instead, you can either `.capitalize()` the input, or lowercase the `"Red"` it matches to:

```
# .capitalize() the input
if color.capitalize in rainbow:
    # code...

# lowercase the "Red"
rainbow = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "voilet"]
```

That will do the trick. Do note that violet is spelled voilet, I'm not sure if that is another language so I left it unchanged.

Other things that you should take note are:

1. The convention of naming variables is with lowercase with underscores. Capitalized names are usually used for classes. You can read more about the conventions in the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
2. There is a `+=` when you want to do `counter = counter + 1`